# Loopback 4 empty database before a test

Tags: javascript, loopback

I want to empty the database before my acceptance test cases.

In my `aircraft.controller.acceptance.ts` I have

```
import { givenEmptyDatabase } from './helpers/database.helpers';
...
before(givenEmptyDatabase);
...
describe( ... ) { ... }
```

in `database.helpers.ts` I try to act according to the [LoopBack 4 documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Testing-your-application.html#clean-the-database-before-each-test)

```
import {AircraftRepository} from '../../src/repositories';
import {testdb} from '../fixtures/datasources/testdb.datasource';

export async function givenEmptyDatabase() {
  await new AircraftRepository(testdb).deleteAll();
}
```

but it's never described what the `testdb.datasource.ts` should look like. I have tried to make it look similar to my regular `db.datasource.ts`, but I'm not sure what to export..

```
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {juggler, AnyObject} from '@loopback/repository';
const config = require('./db.datasource.json');

export class DbDataSource extends juggler.DataSource {
  static dataSourceName = 'db';

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.config.db', {optional: true})
    dsConfig: AnyObject = config
  ) {
    super(dsConfig);
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `lb4 datasource` command to create a datasource named `testdb` ?

Comment: Yes I have. It will generate the datasource similar to the last one I brought out in my initial post. I'm just getting into LoopBack and can't figure out what type of argument the repository needs as a consturctor

Comment: how do you make your tests now which database to use? I tried to do the app.datasource(testdb) but it's not working, when i run npm test still tries to connect to origial MySQL database, can you please post your full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got an answer from the [@loopback/repository](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/packages/repository). testdb.datasource.ts should look like this:

```
import { juggler } from '@loopback/repository';

export const testdb: juggler.DataSource = new juggler.DataSource({
  name: 'db',
  connector: 'memory'
});
```

Comment: My PR was merged and now the documentation includes this answer as well: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Testing-your-application.html#create-a-test-datasource